# Unclear which Python version is used with Remote Debugging (Eclipse Pydev)

Tags: python, eclipse, version, pydev, remote-debugging

The following guides helped me a lot with setting up Eclipse Pydev (on my local machine) and Remote debugging (on a virtual machine):

http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html

http://brianfisher.name/content/remote-debugging-python-eclipse-and-pydev

If I understand things correctly, the application that I'm debugging has to be started on the remote host. So, the application uses the remote Python version.

Now, after the pydevd.settrace(), Eclipse (local host) tells me that it uses local python files in the stacktrace.
Is this because of the path mapping in pydevd_file_utils.py (PATHS_FROM_ECLIPSE_TO_PYTHON)?
Because some of the files are outside these mappings (threading for example).

Imagine the following case: I'm debugging my application on a production like (virtual) machine (Python 2.4) but my Eclipse is hosted on a newer dev machine (Python 2.7 by default). Will the application run under the remote 2.4 python? Or under the local 2.7 python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.
I needed to test this remote debugger approach.

Let me explain how I found out:

I have a local system with python 2.6.5.
I created a new remote system (virtual machine in this case) with python 2.7.3.
Then I shared the following script:

```
import pydevd
print 'hello world'

# call debugger server to handle this breakpoint
pydevd.settrace('10.31.94.156', stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)

# fron now on the host (debugger server) has control over breakpoints,
# variables, stepping through code etc.
print 'hi again'
import sys
print sys.version  # 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:08:41)
                   # [GCC 4.6.3]

# now use a 2.7 feature: 
x = {i : chr(65+i) for i in range(4)}  # dict comprehension
print x  # {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D'}

import socket
print socket.gethostname()  # my virtual machine name

print 'done'
```

Of course I added some breakpoints in Eclipse on my hostmachine. It's funny to see that the local interpreter gives errors about the list comprehension, while it **does** actually run. And it also has variable x nicely displayed in the debuggers Variables pane.

Conclusion: the remote interpreter is used to run / evaluate code.
The debugger server helps you ad

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to determine the current Python version.

## via code:

```
python -c 'import sys; print sys.version'

2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:37:08) 
[GCC 4.8.1]
```

and via

## direct command:

```
python -V

Python 2.7.5+
```

also

## hostname:

```
print socket.gethostname()
```

Comment: Thanks, but under which Python version will the Debugger run the code? Is that the host-python or the guest-python version?

Comment: I don't know. I've added how to get the host name -- add it and see what it gives you, the local machine name or remote.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code and not sure if it is v2 or v3 you can use

```
import sys
try:
    print sys.version
except:
    print(sys.version)
```

Comment: Thanks, but under which Python version will the Debugger run the code? Is that the host-python or the guest-python version?